# How do I average values in a field per ID with Geometry Nodes?

Tags: geometry-nodes

[image]

This spreadsheet corresponds to a point cloud I have generated in Blender 3.6 geometry nodes.

What I want to do is average together the positions of points with the same ID. Do you know how it could be done?

The attribute statistics node doesn't work for what I want, because it outputs a single value, and I want a field of averages with as many values as there are IDs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use *Accumulate Field* node, which allows you to group elements. One to sum up all values, one to count the number of values in a group, and then you can calculate the average. For example below I'm reproducing *Scale Elements* node's functionality by calculating the average position for each mesh island (I only set ID to make it clear it can work with ID):

[image]

Comment: OK thank you, that seems to work for what I want, as far as I can see...